# Android Studio, problema con las Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

soy nuevo con esto de Android, el problema es que después de instalarlo e iniciar un nuevo proyecto, al ir a la ventana de las activities estas aparecen sin nada en ellas, ni siquiera el "Hola Mundo" y cuando agrego un botón tampoco aparece y me lanza el siguiente problema
[image: Problema]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Cuando empiezas con Android lo mejor es que uses el wizard que trae Android Studio para crear tus Activity. Dispone de varios modelos que se suelen adaptar al tipo de aplicación que necesitas y a partir de ahí empiezas a modificar y vas entendiendo como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puede ser por varias razones:

**Primero**. Agregue la biblioteca como una dependencia en el mismo archivo `build.gradle`.

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

**Segundo**. Agregar restricciones a tus vistas. Ejemplo:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

**Tercero**. Haz click en algún widget de tu paleta de componentes (Button, EditText, TextView, etc...) y luego haz click derecho encima de el, en la opción llamada `Constraint Layout`, selecciona `Infer constraints`.

**Cuarto**. Tener tu XML correctamente para usar `Constraint Layout`, Ejemplo:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Si nada de esto funciona entonces, será cambiar a `LinearLayout` o cualquier otro.

Answer (score 0):

la verdad que muchas veces tenemos ese problema yo en lo general aplico el relative layout eso te puede funcionar

> 

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```